# Один запрос или 2 запроса?

Tags: mysql, php, sql

В таблице хранятся данные, отличающиеся полем `status`.
Поле может принимать значения 1, 2, 3.
Мне нужно написать запрос, который вытянет все строки в типом 1, 2. Проблема в том, что на странице эти данные я должен отобразить в разных местах и не хочется делать лишний цикл:

```
foreach($rows as $val){
   $data[$val->type][] = $val;
}
```

Чтобы потом в 2-х местах страницы делать еще 2 цикла:

```
foreach($data[1] as $val){
// For type = 1
}

foreach($data[2] as $val){
// For type = 2
}
```

Comment: А что мешает получить данные одним запросом, а разделение данных провести в момент получения строк с базы?

Например, так (если грубо):

    $resultStatus1 = array();
    $resultStatus2 = array();
    while ($row = fetch_row()) {
        if (1 == $row->status) {
            $resultStatus1[] = $row;
        } else {
            $resultStatus2[] = $row;
        }
    }

добавив, конечно, свою логику.

Comment: А если все строки получаются одним `fetch_all`, то можно разделение провести в первом же цикле:

    ...
    $rows = fetch_all(...);
    $rowsWithStatus2 = array();
    
    foreach($rows as $row){
        if ($row['status'] == 1)
            print_r($row);
        else
            $rowsWithStatus2[] = $row;
    }
    
    foreach($rowsWithStatus2 as $row){
        print_r($row);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Jony](/users/18030/jony), БД вам не сможет поделить данные на два массива (кроме как в два запроса). Не бойтесь лишнего цикла, он вряд ли сожрет больше времени, чем время, затраченное на передачу данных (не на нахождение) от скрипта к БД и наоборот.